# Why is the Laplace tranform of the pdf of a random variable called the Laplace transform of that variable?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, laplace-transform, moment-generating-functions

We know that moment generating function of a random variable $X$ is $$M(t)=E[e^{tX}]$$ and if we replace $t$ with $-s$ then we get the Laplace transform as follows: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-sx}f(x)dx$$ Now this is actually the Laplace transform of the pdf of the random variable $X$. Sometimes (actually in my observation every time) this is called the Laplace transform of the random variable. I want to know why it is said so when it is actually the Laplace transform of the pdf of that random variable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it's because it gets tedious to say "the Laplace transform of the pdf of $X$".

Comment: yes I also felt the same but sometimes it can cause some confusion (as in my case, I almost spent an hour figuring out this).

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}]$ can also be regarded as a generalization of the usual Laplace transform, just as the characteristic function $\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$ is a generalization of the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nothing profound.

"The Lapace transform of the probability density function for a random variable" is way too many words to keep saying and writing.

"The Lapace transform of the random variable" is a bit quicker to say.

Mathematicians are lazy.

That is okay as long as the true meaning is understood.   Although things like this *do* cause confusion when first encountered.

That is all.